# Why does `snotez` throw an error when trying to start a chapter?

Tags: chapters, warnings, marginnote, undefined, snotez

I use `snotez` to write margin notes and it works very well unless I use I use the command `\chapter`. If I used it, the editor (TeXStudio) throws and error by pointing to the end of document lineand it says 'undefined control sequence. `\end{document}`'. It also shows a warning message 'Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.'

Removing `\chapter{Chapter}` in the code below makes it work very well

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}


\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
% BEGIN_FOLD

    \geometry{twoside=true, showframe=true, inner=5mm, outer=5mm, includemp=true, bindingoffset=5mm, marginparsep=3.5mm, marginparwidth=60mm}

    \geometry{top=20mm, vmarginratio=3:5, includehead=true, includefoot=true, headheight=8pt, headsep=14pt, footskip=5mm}

% END_FOLD



\usepackage{mdframed}
% BEGIN_FOLD

    % ===== Begin skipbelow patch =====
    \makeatletter
    \xpatchcmd{\endmdframed}
    {\aftergroup\endmdf@trivlist\color@endgroup}
    {\endmdf@trivlist\color@endgroup\@doendpe}
    {}{}
    \makeatother
    % ===== End skipbelow patch =====

    % ===== Frames templates =====
    \newcommand{\frameSideNote}{Side Note Frame}
    \global \mdfdefinestyle{\frameSideNote}{
        % Line
        linecolor=DodgerBlue1, linewidth=0.5mm,
        topline=false, bottomline=false,
        skipabove=\baselineskip, skipbelow=0.5\baselineskip,
        innertopmargin=0\baselineskip, innerbottommargin=0.3\baselineskip,  innerleftmargin=0.5mm, innerrightmargin=0.5mm,
        %
        % Frame
        frametitlerule=false,
        frametitlefont=\footnotesize \bfseries, frametitlealignment=\justifying,
        frametitleaboveskip=1.76mm, frametitlebelowskip=1.76mm,
        nobreak=false, needspace=3\baselineskip
                                            }




% END_FOLD

\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{snotez}
% BEGIN_FOLD

    \setsidenotes{marginnote=true}
    \setsidenotes{text-format=\raggedright\normalsize}
    \setsidenotes{perpage=false}

    % Marker Settings
    \setsidenotes{note-mark-sep=\hspace{1mm}}

    \newcommand{\colorSideNoteMarker}{DodgerBlue2}

    \setsidenotes{note-mark-format={
        \textsuperscript{\textbf{\color{\colorSideNoteMarker} #1}}}%
                                    }

    \setsidenotes{text-mark-format={
            \textsuperscript{\textbf{\color{\colorSideNoteMarker} #1}}}%
                                    }


    % ===== Begin defining a instructor side notes =====

        \newboolean{InstructorMode}
        \setboolean{InstructorMode}{true}

        \newcommand{\sidenoteInstructor}[2][]{
            \ifthenelse{\boolean{InstructorMode}}{
                \sidenote[#1][]{#2}
            }{}
        }

        % Options to turn the side notes on or off  
        \newcommand{\setInstructorModeOn}{\setboolean{InstructorMode}{true}}
        \newcommand{\setInstructorModeOff}{\setboolean{InstructorMode}{false}}

    % ===== End defining a instructor side notes =====

% END_FOLD




\begin{document}


\chapter{Chapter}

\cleardoublepage

\paragraph{Page with larger right margin}
This \sidenote{note without determining \texttt{voffset}}  paper proposes an improved  single-diode modeling approach for PV modules suitable for a broad range of the PV technologies available today, including modules \sidenote[\baselineskip][]{note with determining \texttt{voffset}} on tandem cell structures. After establishing the model (which has an overall of seven parameters), the paper devises a methodology to estimate its parameters  using Standard Test Conditions (STC) data, Nominal Operating Cell Temperature (NOCT) data, and temperature coefficients values as provided in most manufacturers' datasheets. Simulation results and their comparison \marginnote{Right margin notes work well} with a previous work show a very accurate prediction of critical points in the current-voltage characteristics curve. \sidenoteInstructor{instructor side note} The precise prediction happens for both STC and NOCT conditions and the error in predicting maximum \sidenoteInstructor{instructor side note} power point lies \sidenoteInstructor[2\baselineskip]{instructor side note} within $1\%$ limit, and the error in its corresponding voltage and current is almost always within $2\%$ limit. Further, for both maximum power point and open-circuit voltage, the statistical variance
around manufacturer measurements
%
\sidenote{\begin{mdframed}[style=\frameSideNote, frametitle=My title]
        My Note
            \end{mdframed}} 
%
due to temperature changes is demonstrated to be low for five various module technologies.


\paragraph{Page with larger right margin}
This paper proposes an improved single-diode modeling approach for PV modules suitable for a broad range of the PV technologies available today, including modules on tandem cell structures. After establishing the model (which has an overall of seven parameters), the paper devises a methodology to estimate its parameters using Standard Test Conditions (STC) data, Nominal Operating Cell Temperature (NOCT) data, \marginnote{Right margin notes work well} and temperature coefficients values as provided in most manufacturers' datasheets. Simulation results and their comparison with a previous work show a very accurate prediction of critical points in the current-voltage characteristics curve. The precise prediction happens for both STC and NOCT conditions and the error in predicting maximum power point lies within $1\%$ limit, and the error in its corresponding voltage and current is almost always within $2\%$ limit. Further, for both maximum power point
%
\sidenote[][]{\begin{mdframed}[style=\frameSideNote, frametitle=My title]
        My Note
            \end{mdframed}}
%
and open-circuit voltage, the statistical variance around manufacturer measurements due to temperature changes is demonstrated to be low for five various module technologies.



\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it. Just use `\setsidenotes{perpage=true}`, or `\setsidenotes{perpage=false} \counterwithout{sidenote}{chapter}`

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}


\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
% BEGIN_FOLD

    \geometry{twoside=true, showframe=true, inner=5mm, outer=5mm, includemp=true, bindingoffset=5mm, marginparsep=3.5mm, marginparwidth=60mm}

    \geometry{top=20mm, vmarginratio=3:5, includehead=true, includefoot=true, headheight=8pt, headsep=14pt, footskip=5mm}

% END_FOLD



\usepackage{mdframed}
% BEGIN_FOLD

    % ===== Begin skipbelow patch =====
    \makeatletter
    \xpatchcmd{\endmdframed}
    {\aftergroup\endmdf@trivlist\color@endgroup}
    {\endmdf@trivlist\color@endgroup\@doendpe}
    {}{}
    \makeatother
    % ===== End skipbelow patch =====

    % ===== Frames templates =====
    \newcommand{\frameSideNote}{Side Note Frame}
    \global \mdfdefinestyle{\frameSideNote}{
        % Line
        linecolor=DodgerBlue1, linewidth=0.5mm,
        topline=false, bottomline=false,
        skipabove=\baselineskip, skipbelow=0.5\baselineskip,
        innertopmargin=0\baselineskip, innerbottommargin=0.3\baselineskip,  innerleftmargin=0.5mm, innerrightmargin=0.5mm,
        %
        % Frame
        frametitlerule=false,
        frametitlefont=\footnotesize \bfseries, frametitlealignment=\justifying,
        frametitleaboveskip=1.76mm, frametitlebelowskip=1.76mm,
        nobreak=false, needspace=3\baselineskip
                                            }




% END_FOLD

\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{snotez}
% BEGIN_FOLD

    \setsidenotes{marginnote=true}
    \setsidenotes{text-format=\raggedright\normalsize}

    % ===== Solution =====

        % 1. either set
        \setsidenotes{perpage=true}

        % 2. or set
%       \setsidenotes{perpage=false} \counterwithout{sidenote}{chapter}

    % Marker Settings
    \setsidenotes{note-mark-sep=\hspace{1mm}}

    \newcommand{\colorSideNoteMarker}{DodgerBlue2}

    \setsidenotes{note-mark-format={
        \textsuperscript{\textbf{\color{\colorSideNoteMarker} #1}}}%
                                    }

    \setsidenotes{text-mark-format={
            \textsuperscript{\textbf{\color{\colorSideNoteMarker} #1}}}%
                                    }


    % ===== Begin defining a instructor side notes =====

        \newboolean{InstructorMode}
        \setboolean{InstructorMode}{true}

        \newcommand{\sidenoteInstructor}[2][]{
            \ifthenelse{\boolean{InstructorMode}}{
                \sidenote[#1][]{#2}
            }{}
        }

        % Options to turn the side notes on or off  
        \newcommand{\setInstructorModeOn}{\setboolean{InstructorMode}{true}}
        \newcommand{\setInstructorModeOff}{\setboolean{InstructorMode}{false}}

    % ===== End defining a instructor side notes =====

% END_FOLD




\begin{document}


\chapter{Chapter}

\paragraph{Page with larger right margin}
This \sidenote{note without determining \texttt{voffset}}  paper proposes an improved  single-diode modeling approach for PV modules suitable for a broad range of the PV technologies available today, including modules \sidenote[\baselineskip][]{note with determining \texttt{voffset}} on tandem cell structures. After establishing the model (which has an overall of seven parameters), the paper devises a methodology to estimate its parameters  using Standard Test Conditions (STC) data, Nominal Operating Cell Temperature (NOCT) data, and temperature coefficients values as provided in most manufacturers' datasheets. Simulation results and their comparison \marginnote{Right margin notes work well} with a previous work show a very accurate prediction of critical points in the current-voltage characteristics curve. \sidenoteInstructor{instructor side note} The precise prediction happens for both STC and NOCT conditions and the error in predicting maximum \sidenoteInstructor{instructor side note} power point lies \sidenoteInstructor[2\baselineskip]{instructor side note} within $1\%$ limit, and the error in its corresponding voltage and current is almost always within $2\%$ limit. Further, for both maximum power point and open-circuit voltage, the statistical variance
around manufacturer measurements
%
\sidenote{\begin{mdframed}[style=\frameSideNote, frametitle=My title]
        My Note
            \end{mdframed}} 
%
due to temperature changes is demonstrated to be low for five various module technologies.


\paragraph{Page with larger right margin}
This paper proposes an improved single-diode modeling approach for PV modules suitable for a broad range of the PV technologies available today, including modules on tandem cell structures. After establishing the model (which has an overall of seven parameters), the paper devises a methodology to estimate its parameters using Standard Test Conditions (STC) data, Nominal Operating Cell Temperature (NOCT) data, \marginnote{Right margin notes work well} and temperature coefficients values as provided in most manufacturers' datasheets. Simulation results and their comparison with a previous work show a very accurate prediction of critical points in the current-voltage characteristics curve. The precise prediction happens for both STC and NOCT conditions and the error in predicting maximum power point lies within $1\%$ limit, and the error in its corresponding voltage and current is almost always within $2\%$ limit. Further, for both maximum power point
%
\sidenote[][]{\begin{mdframed}[style=\frameSideNote, frametitle=My title]
        My Note
            \end{mdframed}}
%
and open-circuit voltage, the statistical variance around manufacturer measurements due to temperature changes is demonstrated to be low for five various module technologies.



\end{document}
```